# Handling client/server messages?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, client-server, ooad

From my client/server I receive serialized data, once the data is deserialized, it goes into a command handler where `receivedData.Action` is the `ClientMessage`:

```
Command._handlers[receivedData.Action].Handle(receivedData.Profile);
```

The command handler will work out the client message and return the response that should be given to the client.

I have an enum for the client messages as follow:

```
public enum ClientMessage
{
    INIT = 1,
    NEW_PROFILE,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_EMAIL,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_PASSWORD,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_PHONE,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_DATE,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_SECRET_ANSWER,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_POSTAL_CODE,
    UPDATE_SUCCESS,
    PING,
    PONG,
    QUIT
}
```

What I am having a difficult is how to have all the actions written, for example:

- Should I have a separated enum for what the client sends and another for what the server should reply with ?
- Or should I have a single enum with all messages and follow it as requested ?
- Or how should I go about defining the messages and handling it ?

This is what my server/client currently does just to give you a better view:

1. Server starts
2. Client connects
3. Client send auth to server
4. Server verify client and send connected approval message
5. Client will from there start sending and updating profiles to the server

This is roughly an example only.

IPacketHandler

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
    MyCommunicationData Handle(ProfileData profile);
}
```

Command

```
public class Command
{
    public static Dictionary<ClientMessage, IPacketHandler> _handlers = new Dictionary<ClientMessage, IPacketHandler>()
    {
        {ClientMessage.INIT, new Init()},
        {ClientMessage.NEW_PROFILE, new NewProfile()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_EMAIL, new UpdateEmail()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_PASSWORD, new UpdatePassword()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_PHONE, new UpdatePhone()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_DATE, new UpdateDate()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_SECRET_ANSWER, new UpdateSecretAnswer()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_PROFILE_POSTAL_CODE, new UpdatePostalCode()},
        {ClientMessage.UPDATE_SUCCESS, new Success()},
        {ClientMessage.PING, new Ping()},
        {ClientMessage.PONG, new Pong()},
        {ClientMessage.QUIT, new Quit()},
    };
}
```

Example of the INIT

```
public class Init : IPacketHandler
{
    public MyCommunicationData Handle(ProfileData profile)
    {
        // Some verification to auth the client here 
        // bla bla
        // return response
        return new MyCommunicationData() { Action = ClientMessage.CONNECTED };
    }
}
```

PS: If my title is off and you have a better suggestion let me know or if you can go ahead and update it, I was not sure of how to describe this in English.

Comment: I wouldn't tag this question with client-server, it has to do more with Object Oriented design than client-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about how to design the class and interactions as I understood it, then I would - and it's totally dependant on the specifics of your application - separate this big Enumerations type into separate, smaller ones that are more descriptive of what they do, and of your intentions, for example, `ProfileAction`, `ActionResult`, `PingStatus` etc.. Then when you're using these enums, you make sure that you get compiler-time checks that you're doing it correctly, otherwise, what you're doing is almost like just passing strings.

It also has to do with sticking to Single Responsibility principle in OO design: an object should have single responsibility. Your enum as it stands now has more than one responsibility.

With issues like these, I find it helpful to look at what .NET framework does: for example look at [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) and how it uses PingStatus enumerations and other enumerations as well.

Comment: My question is mostly in regards how I should work out the enumerations to threat the client / server requests and responses. For example client connect to server, then it sends an Authentication request to server, server will reply with an Authentication response command. I could make it all in one enumeration so that the same class used to send data can be used to receive, or use 2 different enumerations which will lead into 2 different classes or a derived class from the MyCommunicationData for response to the client. Not sure if I am being clear with what I am having difficult with sorry.

Comment: no problem. Then my answer stands, I think you should just have as many Enumerations as they logically make sense, and then methods should use the enum that it needs. Having extra classes, methods is better than putting unrelated concepts into a single class. It is the S Single Reponsibility principle in SOLID principles for Object Oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'd use an enum at all. They are great inside a peice of code, exposed as communicated value, they are considerably less than great.

For me I'd have a different class per message, not one message with a god property.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean, but in a way I do have a class per message type

Comment: Unless I misunderstoood you have an instance per message of one class with a messagetype property. I'm saying ditch messagetype property and have PingMessage, PongMessage, etc.

Comment: So you are suggesting to remove the comm status(my enum) and do it on demand ? I am currently using the enum to track what was last sent and what it was expecting to receive next etc.

Comment: Hard to say from here, I'm just throwing possibilities about. For instance instead of tracking state you could pass the state machine about and have it 'track' itself...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, would you care to post some fictional sample just so I can get the picture of it ("hack" itself) ?